# infinite loop in Haskell when binding variables

Tags: haskell

the following Haskell code does not terminate, can someone please explain why? Thanks.

```
f = let x = 10 in let x = x * x in x
```

I think the interpreter first binds x : 10,
then evaluates x * x to 100 and binds x : 100,
and the environment becomes x : 100,
then the whole expression evaluates to 100

However, this code does not terminate.

Comment: let expressions are recursive, so when you have `let x = x * x`, it's all the same `x`, not the one from the outer scope.

Comment: if that's the same one, why it doesn't report an error because the lookup of `x` fails?

Comment: Recursive definitions are central to many aspects of Haskell, such as `map f [] = []; map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs`.  We want the instance of `map` to the right of the `=` to be the same as the `map` on the left side of the `=`.  There is even the function `fix` which is defined as `fix f = let x = f x in x`, and it can actually produce valuable results, a trivial one being `fix (1:)`, which creates an infinite lazy list of `1`s that refers to the same `1` over and over again so it won't blow up in RAM.

Comment: Do you mean this is infinite because of the lazy evaluation of `x = x * x`? I think if you first evaluate `x` in the RHS of `x = x * x` then there would be no problem. However, if you first evaluate `x = x * x` without first evaluating the `x` in the RHS, `x` is bound to `x * x`, then evaluating the `x` in `x * x` would lead to this non-termination, right?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? and the vote to close seems very unjustified too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When evaluating a let-statement of the form `let foo = bar in baz`, `foo` is already bound to `bar` while evaluating `bar` - that is definitions are recursive and if there is an outer binding with the same name, it is simply ignored as it is no longer in scope.

In a comment you asked why you don't then get an error about the lookup of `x` failing. The reason for that is that the lookup of `x` does not fail. Haskell knows that `x` is equal to `x * x`, so that's what the lookup produces.

So when `x` is evaluated, it is replaced with its definition `x * x`. To evaluate that it then replaces the first of the `x`s with its definition, yielding `x * x * x`, then `x * x * x * x` and so on ad infinitum.

You might wonder why values are allowed to be recursive that way, so here's an example that is actually useful and does not just lead to an infinite loop: `let xs = 42 : xs in take 2 xs` produces the result `[42, 42]`. Here `xs` is expanded to `42 : xs` and then `42 : 42 : xs` and then it stops because `take 2` only needs the first two elements, so that's where it stops.

And of course when the rhs is a function, it's immediately obvious that it's useful for the definition to be recursive: `let fac = \n -> if n = 0 then 1 else n * fac (n-1)` - here you obviously want `fac` to refer to itself and not some previous definition of `fac`.

Comment: I see, that's exactly what I was thinking. Can I think of this as the lazy evaluation of Haskell?

Comment: Seems like the environment allows binding non-values to variables.

Comment: @xwang: Yes, in a strict language recursive value definitions would not be possible (except in a few special cases like cyclic definitions using data constructors - `let rec xs = 42 :: xs` in OCaml would be an example of that).