# getting <<loop>> message when run haskell programme

Tags: haskell

I have written code like this

```
import System.Environment
import Control.Exception
import Data.List

f :: String -> [String] -> IO ()
f str []       =
    putStrLn "String 2"
f str (x : xs) =
    putStrLn "String 1"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    xs <- getArgs
    let str = head xs
    let xs = tail xs
    f str xs
    return ()
```

but when I compile it and trying to run I always have only answer `<<loop>>`

```
ghc run.hs
./run some_string some_over_arguments
run: <<loop>>
```

What's wrong with this code? I've tryed to hoogle `<<loop>>` but found nothing. If I pass to `f` not `str xs` but `str [some_hardcoded_list]` this code works fine, so I guess this is something wrong with `xs`.

Comment: So what input args are you using? This is what gets assigned to xs. Please paste the whole run command.

Comment: @KLibby for example `$ ./run my_string any_argument` this is exactly what I tiped

Comment: Possible duplicate of [infinite loop in Haskell when binding variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553559/infinite-loop-in-haskell-when-binding-variables)

Comment: You should compile with `-Wall`; when you do, the compiler will warn you when these things happen. And just a by the way: instead of binding the head and then the tail you can just pattern match the `_:_` constructor. It's easier to write and if you do, the compiler will also warn you about the second potential problem in your code (inexhaustive pattern match -- what if `xs` is `[]`?). And besides that incomplete functions like `head` & `tail` are just bad :P

Comment: @MasterMastic thanks, I did not know that `-Wall` exists in haskell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to you see the part where you declare

```
let xs = tail xs
```

this says you want `xs` to be a list that is the *tail of itself* and this causes an infinte loop (which ghc seems to notice ;)) (seen as an definition every constant list `repeat c` would suffice here - technically of course you just get a plain infinite-loop)

so just change it to something like

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    xs <- getArgs
    let str = head xs
    let xs' = tail xs
    f str xs'
    return ()
```

and your code should work as expected ;)

Answer (score 3):

Others have already answered. I just want to add that enabling warnings will point out redefinitions of existing bindings. This also covers this kind of unwanted recursion:

```
> :set -Wall
> xs <- return [1..10::Int]
> let xs = tail xs

<interactive>:11:5: Warning:
    This binding for ‘xs’ shadows the existing binding
      defined at <interactive>:10:1
```

Now, one could think "but in this case I *really* intend to shadow the previous binding", and would be completely correct. Still, renaming the new binding incidentally avoids the problem.

One more reason to add `{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}` at the top of your source file.
(Or enabling warning in your .cabal file, or whatever other build system)